# The slave I/O thread stops because SET @master_heartbeat_period on master failed after changing a character set

Tags: mysql, database-replication, master-slave, codepages

After I have done master-slave replication in test environment, have to change character set. That's what I've done:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_bin
init_connect=‘SET collation_connection = utf8_bin’

[client]
default_character_set = utf8
```

in my.cnf on both servers, after restarts of the servers, done:

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

result:

```
The slave I/O thread stops because SET @master_heartbeat_period on master failed. Error:
```

Tried stop slave; reset slave; start slave; - doesn't help. Tried drop db, create new, when those settings have been done, restore backup into it, after that to replicate this DB - doesn't help. Tried

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

to the only one table that I have, before to create replication from zero point - doesn't help.
Could you please to advise, how to set codepage up with replication working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
init_connect=‘SET collation_connection = utf8_bin’

[client]
default_character_set = utf8
```

Was unnecessary. Without those code replication is working.